# Increment dates by one month for the rows using partition by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with columns `ID, Name, Type, Date`. I have to increment dates automatically by 1 month partitioning by `ID, Name, Type`.

My date starts at 01-01-2000. It should just keep adding next dates automatically for my rows.

I tried adding

```
OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Name, Type ORDER BY DATEADD(Month, 1, 2000-01-01)
```

but SQL Server threw an error.

Actual:

```
ID Name  Type      Date
-----------------------------
1  "A"   Group1    2000-01-01
2  "A"   Group1    2000-01-01
3  "c"   Group2    2000-01-01
4  "c"   Group2    2000-01-01
```

Expected:

```
ID Name  Type      Date
-----------------------------
1  "A"   Group1    2000-01-01
2  "A"   Group1    2000-02-01
3  "c"   Group2    2000-01-01
4  "c"   Group2    2000-02-01
```

and so on

Comment: What is the full code you tried, and what was the exact error message you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following script.

You can check the [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=092347984ed48dfe36f843ad7527f1c0)

```
SELECT A.ID,
A.Name,
A.Type,
DATEADD(MM,(RN-1),A.Date) AS Date
FROM 
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name,ID) RN
    -- You can also apply the PARTITION on Type
    -- Based on your requirement or data nature.
    FROM your_table
)A
```

Output is-

```
ID  Name    Type    Date
1   A       Group1  2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
2   A       Group1  2000-02-01 00:00:00.000
3   c       Group2  2000-01-01 00:00:00.000
4   c       Group2  2000-02-01 00:00:00.000
```